# how to pass xml from controller to other controller in mvc4

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am new to mvc. Exploring the ways to pass value from action method of one controller to other controller. Is this possible to pass xml as value from one controller to other in httppost?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass from one controller to another"?  Controllers generally don't directly invoke one another.  At a higher level, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think this question needs more details. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Controller actions are not meant to communicate with each other directly. Action return Views, and views can then communicate user generated information in a structured manner to another controller action.

Comment: you can pass that xml as a string then serialize it in the controller

Comment: I am trying to use controller to controller as a web service call and get response from that controller to my current controller

Comment: Are you envisioning these are two seperate servers or are you really planning on making a web call from a server back to its self?  If the second example just don't do it.  The overhead for such communications is not worth the loose abstraction. If you are doing the second then check out HttpClient for the client controller and replace the server controller with WebApi.

Comment: If one controller is outputting a page with a form that will be posted to another controller, and you need to include some data generated by the first controller in the posted message to the second one, just place it in a hidden field (`<input type=hidden">value</input>`) in that form. You will have to encode it though so that the xml can be embedded in the html, and possible sign and/or encrypt it for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is available at pretty much any time in a controller, and is very simple to use.

```
Session["ArbitraryKeyString"] = "Assign any object";
string arbitraryString = (string)(Session["ArbitraryKeyString"] ?? "Session returns null if key not found");
```

Just be sure to cast it back to the type you need, because it's stored as a Object. You can do this during server calls, since they're all simply external ways to call controller functions, and the values will persist between pages and calls.

Answer (score -1):

Passing it as a parameter is probably your best option. Try using something like return RedirectToAction(ActionName, ControllerName, RouteValues);.